# K - means, expected shape of the curve

Tags: machine-learning, inference, k-means

I want to understand what happens as we increase the number of clusters using k- means, what is the expected shape of the curve showing the average distance between points and their assigned clusters?

- It should be concave, having its maximum value at the optimum number of clusters with all other values decreasing around it.
- It should be convex, having its minimum value at the optimum number of clusters with all other values increasing around it.
- It should decrease slowly until the optimal number of clusters is reached, then decrease sharply afterward.
- It should decrease sharply until the optimal number of clusters is reached, then decrease slowly afterward.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: This feels like a homework question

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Answer (score 1):

Number 4 sounds the more sensible. Think about if k=the true number of clusters, then most of the points (except the outliers) will be nearby the centroid. After that, increasing k, will always lead in a decrease but more slowly. Up until k=n (where n is the number of data points) and your distance is now 0.

Comment: Please be cautious about answering homework-type questions. Our policy is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Apologies, I'll keep the guideline in mind in the future.